# CSS html paragraph moving on hover

Tags: html, css

I have some issue with a paragraph moving on hover, after some research I found many issue related with padding and margin so I tried some edit like :

- to remove the padding
- to remove the margin
- to remove line-height
- set position static or fixed on hover

Nothing worked, this mostly looks like a layout issue but I'm not very accommodate with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
#main-footer p{
    font-size:16px;
}

#main-footer hr{
    margin-top:0;
    border-color:#19191d;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p{
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p.address{
    padding-left: 28px;
}

#main-footer .container a{
    color: #ffffff;
}

#main-footer .container a:hover{
    color: #d6c087;
    position: static;
}

#main-footer .container a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-footer img{
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 24px !important;
}

.social-links {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.social-links li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 5px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 0 transparent;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a {
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size:18px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#38A5DB;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
        <hr>
        <h4>Tittle</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                CP City</p></a>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                    CP City</p></a>

            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                <ul class="social-links">
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d4"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d3"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>Footer copyright</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this should work:

```
p:hover {
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

p {
    transition:.25s;
}
```

Try it in action in the snippet below.

```css
#main-footer p{
    font-size:16px;
}

#main-footer hr{
    margin-top:0;
    border-color:#19191d;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p{
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p.address{
    padding-left: 28px;
}

#main-footer .container a{
    color: #ffffff;
}

#main-footer .container a:hover{
    color: #d6c087;
    position: static;
}

#main-footer .container a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-footer img{
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 24px !important;
}

.social-links {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.social-links li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 5px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 0 transparent;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a {
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size:18px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#38A5DB;
}

p:hover {
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

p {
    transition:.25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
        <hr>
        <h4>Tittle</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                CP City</p></a>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                    CP City</p></a>

            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                <ul class="social-links">
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d4"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d3"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>Footer copyright</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what is the differences between our answers... :D

Answer (score 0):

I've added this:

```
p:hover {
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

The 1 second transition is just for the example, and also you can come up with better css selector for those paragraphs.

```css
#main-footer p{
    font-size:16px;
}

#main-footer hr{
    margin-top:0;
    border-color:#19191d;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p{
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

#main-footer .col-sm-4 p.address{
    padding-left: 28px;
}

#main-footer .container a{
    color: #ffffff;
}

#main-footer .container a:hover{
    color: #d6c087;
    position: static;
}

#main-footer .container a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-footer img{
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 24px !important;
}

.social-links {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.social-links li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 5px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 0 transparent;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a {
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size:18px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-out;
}

.social-links li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#38A5DB;
}

p:hover {
      padding-left: 10px;
      transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
        <hr>
        <h4>Tittle</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                CP City</p></a>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="" target="_blank"><p><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname
                </p>
                <p class="address">address<br/>
                    CP City</p></a>

            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                <ul class="social-links">
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d4"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="scrollimation fade-right d3"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>Footer copyright</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Tittle

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname </img>
            
            <p class="address">address
            CP City</p></a>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="assets/icons8-google-maps-48.png" alt=""> Prettyname </img>
            
            <p class="address">address
                CP City</p></a>

        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
            <ul class="social-links">
                <li class="scrollimation fade-right d4"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                <li class="scrollimation fade-right d3"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Footer copyright</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

If this solves your problem, plz mark it as your answer.